Build execuable that depend on codes that belonged to Godot source code using SCons
Here environment:
Windows 11
Visual Studio 2022 with Windows 11 SDK, MSVC v143 for complier
vscode as editor
SCons v4.8.1 with python 3.12.7
Godot 4.4 source code, git repo here
I am not very familar with how to link lib to source code. This situation is more complex than that, I feel, because I want to use some code in open source project, the io module of Godot, to do some experiments.
Here is the dir relation setup of Godot source project and my experiments project (only one source file: input.expr.cpp):
directory relationship
D:
 -> Godot
   -> other no need src
   -> core
      -> io 
   -> platform
      -> windows
 -> Experiment
   -> input.expr.cpp

When I write code, the Intellisense just work fine , have auto-complete, code snippet thanks the c_cpp_properties.json writed like this, you can see where the include path is.
c_cpp_properties.json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Users/15070/Workspace/godot",
                "C:/Users/15070/Workspace/godot/platform/windows"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Users\\15070\\Program\\VisualStudio\\IDE\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.38.33130\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}

My input.expr.cpp, just include some .h belonged to the Godot source code and use some class in it like this
It is worth mentioning that those header files have complex include relation in code.
input.expr.cpp
#include "core/io/file_access.h"
#include "core/io/file_access_encrypted.h"

int main(){
    FileAccess * file;
    // use some class decraled in file_access and file_access_encrypted
    // ...
    retunr 0;
}

Finally, completed the edits for input.expr.cpp, then I try to build this use SCons.
First I write SConstruct to instruct the build work (I don't know how build work, how SCons work, So I totally getted lost in it for 4 hours more wity the silly me and the silly github copliot, so I come to here to ask question), code in SConstruct is most given by github copliot or Internet, I am not really know what going on.
SConstruct
import os

depends = [
    "C:/Users/15070/Workspace/experiment",
    "C:/Users/15070/Workspace/godot",
    "C:/Users/15070/Workspace/godot/platform/windows",
]
current_path = os.environ['PATH']

additional_paths = [
    "C:/Users/15070/Program/VisualStudio/IDE/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.38.33130/bin/Hostx64/x64/",
]

path = current_path + os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join(additional_paths)

env = Environment(
    CPPPATH=depends,
    ENV={"PATH":path},
    CXXFLAGS=[
        "/std:c++17", 
        "/Zc:__cplusplus"
    ],
)

env.Program("input.expr.cpp")



Run SCons in terminal, Here is the key log messages:
cl /Foinput.expr.obj /c input.expr.cpp /std:c++17 /Zc:__cplusplus /nologo /I. /IC:\Users\15070\Workspace\godot /IC:\Users\15070\Workspace\godot\platform\windows
input.expr.cpp
link /nologo /OUT:input.expr.exe input.expr.obj
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can not open “C:\windows\lnk{D7A6DFED-1BA3-4827-958F-C95087FD1366}.tmp”

SCons give me the input.exprt.obj file correctly, but failed when linking. Hmmm, the obj file is generaed correctly but linking failed, what that mean?
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: can not open “C:\windows\lnk{D7A6DFED-1BA3-4827-958F-C95087FD1366}.tmp”
Seems lost some lib, but what it is, a tmp lib? I am sure that there is no complied lib in Godot source code. 
Can some one teach me how to do those thing:
1. Find one third pary project
2. In my own project, do include .h file that from open source project
3. Build own project use SCons

Here is my PATH environment variable.
By the way, I have builded Godot execuable use its source code with SCons.
PATH
C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\HP\OMEN-Broadcast\Common;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\lua-5.4.2_Win64_bin\;C:\Program Files\HP\HP One Agent;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\Users\15070\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_412\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;

TEMP USERPROFILE with C:/Users/15070
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp


Please paste the text for your PATH, not a screen shot. Also what's the value of TEMP ?   The .lnk file is a file to hold all the command line arguments being passed to link. Likely that's the real issue.. I'd bet you don't have permissions to write into c:\windows ?

I just editted question to add PATH and TEMP value, hope you can find some trace from it. My windows 11 is always said no permission, no permission in daily use when I open file or install program, may be you are correct.  The question is I even have no c:\windows folder, but have c:\Windows, it is the crucial? @bdbaddog

I tried it out, yes it is the permisson causing link problem. There no longer have 1104 error code. A nice step! However, it starts complain that missing a lot of thing called external file, . Try to check it out.

Basically, it's no longer safe to overwrite environment variable ENV in this way on Windows, so this line: ENV={"PATH":path}, is going to be at least part of your problem.  You need to fetch and apply at least %TEMP% and possibly also %COMPSEC and %USERPROFILE% from the external environment to the execution environment.  In SCons, env['ENV'] is called the execution environment, it's the set of environment variables presented to the build backend commands (like cl.exe) when they're called to actually do the building work.
If you want to follow the model you've already used, it might look something like this (omitting your existing details):
current_temp = os.environ["TEMP"]
current_profile = os.environ["USERPROFILE"]
current_comspec = os.environ["COMPSEC"]

env = Environment(
    CPPPATH=depends,
    ENV={
        "PATH": path,
        "TEMP": current_temp,
        "USERPROFILE": current_profile,
        "COMPSEC": current_comspec,
    },
    CXXFLAGS=["/std:c++17", "/Zc:__cplusplus"],
)

Not saying that's going to fix your build but it's a starting point.

Yeah. Exactly your answer solved the PERMISSION problem I meet.

Have any ideas on missing external file when building? The link code , Godot source code, is out of the current project folder.

Usually missing files refers to the contents of CPPPATH. Which you're setting - maybe not to the full set that's needed? For CPPPATH, you can add to what's already set rather than writing it unconditionally, in case it's overwriting some stuff the Godot build has already set up.  Like" env.Append(CPPPATH=[list-of-paths-to-add].
